# Which files besides .htaccess should I have at a site which uses a domain mask?

Tags: .htaccess, domain-mask

I have a site A and site B. Site B has a domain mask to Site A such that contents of Site A are visible at Site B.

Site B contains only a .htaccess -file.

**Do I need other files besides .htaccess at the site B?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all requests to site B are mapped to an equivalent request at Site A, then no, you don't.

Comment: So a .htaccess is enough, and I do not need any other files. Do I need to put an empty index.html to Site B for security?

Comment: No.  What would that secure?  http://siteb.foo/ is being mapped to http://sitea.foo/; no one's going to be able to get a generated index of siteb's contents, and anyway there's nothing to secure.

Comment: Even if they asked for your .htaccess, and the request were allowed (Apache ships with requests to .ht* denied ever since SO user Jason Coco submitted a patch for it circa 1998), they'd only get site A's, if any.